# get smartsheet row id by searching column values

Tags: search, smartsheet-api

Is there a way to use the Smartsheet API to search a sheet and get back the IDs of rows where column A = {something} and column B = {something else}?

If this were SQL, it'd be a simple SELECT id FROM sheet WHERE A = 'something' and B = 'something else';

But the documentation for the Smartsheet API makes it seem as if you can only do a blunt text search across the entire sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to query / filter by specific column values today.  This is definitely something we want to add, and it's on the roadmap.

You have two alternatives.  One is to do a "blunt text search", as you have discovered.  Another is to retrieve the sheet, parse it and identify matches locally.  Not as elegant, and more time and labor intensive, but is a viable option.

Comment: Thanks. Are you officially a Smartsheet employee? Couldn't tell from your profile.

Comment: Yes, our team owns API and Webhooks product management.  We monitor the SO traffic in addition to our inbound support channel.  Hope this helps, and definitely hear you re: wanting to be able to filter.

Comment: Has this filter functionality been added to the API since this question has been asked.  I have a couple of projects where sheet filtering would help tremendously.  Thanks

Comment: @avioing - this question is more than 2 years old, has there been any change?