# Smartsheet API C# Filtering Rows by data in a column

Tags: c#, api, smartsheet-api

I am new to API's and Smartsheet.  I am looking to filter a specific set of records  to display in a datagrid.  I have got the connection and data coming in, but i only want to display records for that specific column selection.

ie:  Column A = 200

I also need to know how to filter two columns in the same sheet.  ie: column A = 200, Column C = "Fred"

I think i need to use the IEnumerable includes function but i can't find any examaples of doing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988057/get-smartsheet-row-id-by-searching-column-values/36989065#36989065

Comment: Yes its the same question but Smartsheet's help text is useless other than saying the below

https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#row-include-flags

Row Include Flags
Include Flag Description
columnType Includes columnType attribute in the row's cells indicating the type of the column the cell resides in.
filters Includes filteredOut attribute indicating if the row should be displayed or hidden according to the sheet's filters.
objectValue Includes objectValue attribute on cells containing values. For more information see Cell Reference.

Answer (score 1):

The `include=filters` query string parameter reveals the `filteredOut` field on the row object. This field is a boolean value based on the filters that are applied in the Smartsheet UI.

For instance, if you create a filter in the Smartsheet UI on Column A to only show values equal to 200, your sheet would reflect that filter in the UI. Then, when you get that sheet through the API with `include=filters` set in your query string, the rows that have Column A = 200 (and are visible in the UI) will have the value `"filteredOut": false` in the API response.

The parameter doesn't actually filter the rows out of the API response. You'll have to have logic in your code that does the filtering.

Comment: I am not looking to do that as it defeats the purpose.  I am looking to runtime filter records by passing variables in the C# application/Smartsheet API My question is examples of how this is done as Smartsheets help is very light on

Comment: Andrew, that functionality is not documented because what you're trying to do is not possible with the Smartsheet API. Applying a filter to your data can only be done through the Smartsheet UI. By passing the query parameter that Scott mentioned, the Smartsheet API will return another property on each row that indicates whether a specific row has been filtered out. In order to parse the response and grab the data that you care about, you will always need to write your own custom logic. Using the query parameter just makes it easier to distinguish between which rows you want.